# How come I get different R versions at the same time within RStudio Server?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

So, I upgraded my old RStudio Server installation on my EC2 at Amazon. First step was upgrading RStudio Server. No issues.

Second step was upgrading the R itself.
I upgraded the machines R installation to 3.3.2.

EDIT (inserted after comment): I upgraded R by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Please also note that `which R` on the command line gives `/usr/bin/R`. And that `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` has this line in it; `rsession-which-r=/usr/bin/R`

When starting R through the command line the version is now 3.3.2. But when logging in to the RStudio Server "web page" it says 3.3.0 at startup (after machine reboot). See dump below.

So, I tried fixing this that the RStudio Server stayed at 3.3.0 while the machines version was 3.3.2. I tried for a few days and found no fix until I simply tried the command `version` from within RStudio Server. And it strangely answered 3.3.2.
Anyone else understand or seen this behavior before, that it starts up saying that R is at one version, and then actually is a different version when verifying with the `version` command? And at what version of R is my RStudio Server actually running?

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.


Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.


[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]
```

.... other warnings such as CRAN mirror not https etc...

```
>version

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Comment: _"Second step was upgrading the R itself."_. This is linux, not Windows or macOS, so that could mean 100 different things. You should list the steps you did for the original installation and the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr. Edited text above.